# Setting PHP on IIS ODBC Connection Timeout

Tags: php, iis, odbc

I've inherited an issue on a Joomla site running on PHP 5.5 on IIS 7.5.  Currently it accesses a SQL server through our firewall as part of a query, but this server may not always be available so I wanted to make sure the script dealt with this gracefully.  We connect with

```
$itemodbc = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$itemserver;Database=$itemdatabase;";

$con = odbc_connect($itemodbc,$itemuser,$itempassword) or die('SQL connection error');
```

but if I simulate the server being unavailable by changing the server's IP address this takes ages and eventually the page script (I believe) times out and errors.  What I want to do is set this timeout to 5 or 10 seconds, and if this times out then I can continue the script only using the server's local database content, but I can't find where to set this up.  I've found the mssql.connect_timeout entry in the php.ini but this doesn't make any difference (I'm sure this is for mssql_connect calls, rather than odbc_connect, so this makes sense), and there doesn't seem to be an ODBC equivalent, I've also tried appending "Timeout=10;" to the ODBC connection string, but this also doesn't seem to work.  Hunting round google I have found what seem to be the settings for a Linux system, but obvisously that also isn't helpful.  Where do I need to set this in Windows, or do I need to convert it to another database connection type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you have this solved already, but I would have used some kind of PHP based code to 'test' if the server was online. A quick google showed this might be a possible solution for your problem (just change google.com to the direct route to your server, maybe an IP on a different port, or maybe something like server.companyhost.com)

```
function availableUrl($host, $port=80, $timeout=10) { 
  $fp = fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 
  return $fp!=false;
}

//Return "true" if the url is available, false if not.
if (!availableUrl("www.google.com")) {
    print " some message that the server is down with neat html that suits your needs  ";
    exit;
}else{
    //the connection is ok... proceed 
}
```